# Why wont my rails create an app correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time I create a new app in rails it throws an error related to actionmailer.

it should work basically after:

- rails new example
- cd example
- bundle
- rails s

But throws an error even every time.

I've gotten things to work by copy and pasting a old gemfile and gemfile lock into the new app and it makes it work

Here's the output after rails s:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    89: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    88: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    87: from /Users/user/stack/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    86: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    85: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    84: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    83: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    82: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    81: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    80: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    79: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    78: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    77: from /Users/user/stack/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    76: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    75: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    74: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    73: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    72: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    71: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    70: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    69: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    68: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    67: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    66: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    65: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    64: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    63: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    62: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    61: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    60: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    59: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    58: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    57: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    56: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    55: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    54: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    53: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    52: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    51: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    50: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    49: from config.ru:in `new'
    48: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    47: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    46: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    45: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
    44: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    43: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    89: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    88: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    87: from /Users/user/stack/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    86: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    85: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    84: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    83: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    82: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    81: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    80: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    79: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    78: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    77: from /Users/user/stack/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    76: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    75: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    74: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    73: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    72: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    71: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    70: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    69: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    68: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    67: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    66: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    65: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    64: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    63: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    62: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    61: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    60: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    59: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    58: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    57: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    56: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    55: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    54: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    53: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    52: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    51: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    50: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    49: from config.ru:in `new'
    48: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    47: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    46: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    45: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
    44: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    43: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    42: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    41: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    40: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    38: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    37: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    36: from /Users/user/stack/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    35: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    34: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    33: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    32: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    31: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    30: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    29: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    28: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    27: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    26: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    25: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    24: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    23: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    22: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    21: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    20: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    19: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    18: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    17: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    16: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    15: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    14: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `each'
    13: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:602:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    12: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    11: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    10: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     9: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     8: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     7: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     6: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     5: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     4: from /Users/user/stack/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<main>'
     3: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `configure'
     2: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `instance_eval'
     1: from /Users/user/stack/config/environments/development.rb:34:in `block in <main>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:97:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00007f9c43e2c598> (NoMethodError)
```

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make sure your error output is formatted correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Besides, I am not sure if you have pasted the trace for 1.5 times. Why don't you view the preview before posting?

Comment: Holy humongous stack trace batman!

Comment: This is my first time posting sorry for the format error.

Thanks for the assist @ulferts

Comment: @bens If you can go back and edit the post to make it more readable it will help us help you.  The easier it is for you to read the easier it will be for us.  The edit and preview system is pretty good here! EDIT: Go @ulferts!

Comment: Can you add your Gemfile to the question?

Comment: I can but its just the Rails generated gemfile with no mods. I will if it makes a difference

Comment: Can you post your config/environments/development.rb file? Also run `spring stop` before running `rails s` again?